# rightbarbuttonitem not displaying

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

I have got following code for putting rightbarbuttonitem

```
UIButton* rightbutton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [rightbutton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"share-icon.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [rightbutton addTarget:self action:@selector(share:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:rightbutton] autorelease];
```

But it is not displaying any barbuttonitem. Instead if I use following code then barbutton item appears but problem is i cant set touch event with this code on barbuttonitem.

```
UIImageView *iconView=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"dashboard-icon.png"]];
    UIBarButtonItem *icon = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:iconView];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=icon;
    [icon release];
    [iconView release];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to set an appropriate frame for the `rightbutton`? e.g. `rightbutton.frame = (CGRect){CGPointZero, image.size};`

Also note:

> On iOS 4 and later, the name of the
>   file is not required to specify the
>   filename extension. Prior to iOS 4,
>   you must specify the filename
>   extension.

Comment: My answer contains the sample code. What you need to do is to declare an <code>image</code> variable and set it to your image.

Answer (score 7):

my guess is, that you add the `UIBarButtonItem` to the wrong object! 
you need to add it, to the rootViewController (instead to the `UINavigationController`, as you probably did)

```
YourRootViewController *theRootController = [[YourRootViewController alloc] init];

UINavigationController* navContainer = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:theRootController];

UIButton* rightbutton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [rightbutton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"share-icon.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [rightbutton addTarget:self action:@selector(share:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
 theRootController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightbutton;

[navContainer setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];
[self presentModalViewController:navContainer animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget to set tintColor on the UIBarButtonItem if you are using a white navigation bar.  My buttons were there but invisible.

Answer (score 0):

Using swift 3.0 iOS 10.0

let customButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Right", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(yeah))
        customButton.width = 100.0
       navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = customButton

func yeah(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        print("Yo Your the man/woman")
    }

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem when I set rightBardButtonItems for a child
rather than rootmost viewcontroller

view controller always have navigationitem but that does not necessarily
mean it has a navbar to show it in